# How does the authorization rules are validated by keycloak authorization server using spring rest adapter

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-rest, keycloak-services

I have set up the keycloak server and created the spring rest application with keycloak rest adapters. The Authorizations rules are working fine.

I would like to know about the internal working of the keycloak spring boot rest adapter. How the logged in user's token is validated against policy and permission set in keycloak admin client.

Comment: Read the latter part of this blog post https://sandor-nemeth.github.io/java/spring/2017/06/15/spring-boot-with-keycloak.html

Comment: Hi @ChirdeepTomar, Thanks for the response and the pointing document. The above link explains about basics of Role-Based Authorization which will be available in the access token (JWT.io url you can view the role information). Keycloak provides more fine-grained authorization services which will have permission objects. The permission object will not be available in the access token, and you need to make one more call to the token endpoint to retrieve RPT token which will have the Permission objects. In Spring boot project does it require one more call to determine the permissions?

Comment: Well I would hope so because that information isn't available in access_token or id_token. You might have to read through the adaptor codebase to find that out.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, access token does not contain all these details.

In Keycloak when you are using server side adapters the client will be configured to use the standard flow and not the implicit flow of OIDC.

In standard flow when you login using keycloak IDP your front-end redirects to Keycloak IDP and asks for you credentials. If you have the right credentials login is successful and you are redirected back to your app. In this redirect your app gets a code which it then sends to the back-end rest call. This code is used by spring adapter in the spring boot app to make a call to Keycloak IDP server and it is this call in which the boot application will get the user context to take all the authorization decisions as a response from the Keycloak server.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hey, @pulkit, thanks a lot for this explanation. Is there a way to control which flow and access type should specific (let's say Spring Boot Adapter) use or they usually stick to "Implicit Flow" by default?

Comment: @skryvets Implicit flow is generally used for JS-based adapters(Front-end driven flow) and Standard flow is used for server-side adapters like JBoss adapter, Spring boot adapter.

To control what flow to use, create a new client in Keycloak. You can log in into the admin console of your Keyclaok instance to create a new client. Ideally, each application should use a different client.

While creating a new client you have many configuration items to set and one of these items is the flow parameter. This client will then be used by your application using the client-id parameter.